# Implementing quantum swap operation such that $|x\rangle|f(x)\rangle$ changes to $|x\rangle|f(x+1)\rangle$

Tags: quantum-gate, quantum-state, quantum-algorithms, entanglement, quantum-circuit

Suppose that a quantum state $|\psi\rangle$ in question is $|\psi\rangle \propto \sum_x |x\rangle|f(x)\rangle$.

I want to implement a quantum swap operation such that computational basis $|x\rangle|f(x)\rangle$ becomes $|x\rangle|f(x+1)\rangle$. That is, $|x\rangle|f(x)\rangle \to |x\rangle|f(x+1)\rangle$. This seems to be just about a series of basis swaps, but I am not so sure about this. Can we implement this as a quantum circuit? (For the greatest $x$, $x+1$ is considered to be zero.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Probably the best way to think about this is "subtract 1 from the first register". This is a standard classical computation, and hence you can write out a circuit for it. (Although you'll want to be careful of your boundary conditions.)